# Cron job making date database entry

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, cron

I have a very simple code for a cron job that makes a date entry into an SQL DB:

```
$qry_cron_test  = "INSERT INTO ".$tblprefix."cron_test SET

    create_datetime = '".date("Y-d-m H:i:s")."'";    

    $rs_cron_test   = $db -> Execute($qry_cron_test);
```

The problem is the following:

Between 1st and 12th of every month the date entry is like this - 2014-10-03 07:30:39, which is what i want.

However, when the current date is between 13th and the end of the month, the date entry looks like this - 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Then when 1st comes the entires are all ok again.

I tested this on couple of servers and also locally on Xampp always with the same result.

Any suggestions? What could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have month and day the wrong way around.

```
$qry_cron_test  = "INSERT INTO ".$tblprefix."cron_test SET
    create_datetime = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";    
    $rs_cron_test   = $db -> Execute($qry_cron_test);
```

date("Y-**m**-**d** H:i:s")

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that, unless you need milisecond information, you always store date information in [Unix Timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/). It is lighter to store, since it is only a integer value, is faster to retrieve and is universal, since it is always based on UTC.

Specially in PHP, converting date information to ([`time()`](http://php.net/time) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime)) and from ([`date()`](http://php.net/date)) a unix timestamp is pretty easy. This way no matter where your user is, you can always show correct information in local time with almost no effort.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just do this:

```
insert into cron_test
create_datetime
values
(current_timestamp)
```